# Storing Image path into database

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have the following code to store the path of an image into a database.

The file path is not storing into the database. Although the image name is?

Any ideas of why this is?

```
  <?php

  session_start();  
 error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);


// escape variables for security
$ImageName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['imageName']);


  //getting the filename of the image file.
 $file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];


   $sql="UPDATE images SET imageLoc = '$file_name', imageName = '$ImageName'
    WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION["Username"]."'";
//$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

     if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

  echo "error";

   }

 echo "yess";



 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

The database connection is fine.

Thanks

XHTML Part:

```
  Select image to upload:

    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">


    Name of Image: <input type="text" name="imageName"/>
```

Comment: $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']; only is the file name, you need to define the path where you store it.

Comment: what is being stored?  Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data" `?

Comment: I have all the form tags etc with post. I want to store the file path name such as C:filename.jpg into the database

Comment: You should NOT want the path on the user's machine since that makes no sense. Its also one of the reasons the browser doesn't send you that (also its a security issue). You want the path of where you stored it on the *server.*

Comment: *"The file path is not storing into the database."* - You haven't told it to. Where have you defined the path? *Nowhere*.

Comment: in the form the filetoUpload is uploading an image and that path should be stored into the DB

Comment: That's just the filename. Here, read the manual please http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php and/or see the answer that has been given below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it:

```
/* this->> */ $uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        /* then do this--> */ move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
```

So, you store the path as a $uploads_dir
then, you need to move the file to $uploads_dir...

THEN, your path to store in the database will be = "$uploads_dir/$name"